# Where and how should I implement ScrollViewer in my XAML?

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-4.0, .net-4.0

So if (roughly) my XAML tree is as so:

```
<TabControl Name="tab1">
            <TabItem Header="Untitled" Name="tabMain">
                <Canvas Name="canvasTest" DockPanel.Dock="Right">
                <local:VisualsHost Canvas.ZIndex ="99" x:Name="vshMain"></local:VisualsHost>
                    <ListBox Name="lstTiles" DockPanel.Dock="Right" SelectionMode="Extended" PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="grdMain_MouseRightButtonDown" 
             PreviewMouseRightButtonUp="grdMain_MouseRightButtonUp" MouseDown="lstTiles_MouseDown" >
                    <ListBox.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <ScrollViewer>
                                <ItemsPresenter />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </ListBox.Template>
                        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style>
                                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                    Path=Content.Row}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                    Path=Content.Column}"/>
                                <Setter Property="ListBoxItem.Height" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=lstboxHeight}" />
                                <Setter Property="ListBoxItem.Width" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=lstboxWidth}" />
                                <Setter Property="ListBoxItem.IsHitTestVisible" Value="True" />
                                <Style.Resources>
                                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Blue" Opacity=".3" />
                                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
                                </Style.Resources>
                            </Style>
                        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <Grid ShowGridLines="True" IsItemsHost="True" Background="{DynamicResource LoadedImage}" 
                      Name="grdMain"> 
                            </Grid>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    </ListBox>
            </Canvas>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

Putting the scrollviewer around my listbox did nothing. Placing the ControlTemplate as you see above also does nothing. My grid's width/height (which as you see is set my listboxitem template) dynamically expands and shrinks down but when it expands beyond the size of the window, still, no scroll bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the ListBox is within Canvas it will not have its size adjusted as the container resizes. The Canvas itself can extend beyond the bounds of it's container.

ListBox has ScrollViewer built in for when the list content exceeds the maximum size of the ListBox, but you will never exceed this size, since the ListBox will just grow because it is not constrained by the Canvas.

The DockPanel attached properties you are using will not do anything for the layout. I would suggest replacing the Canvas with a Grid container which will restrain the Listbox size.

Comment: Good answer.  The problem is the Canvas.  @Ilya:  In case you didn't understand Guy's statement that "ListBox has ScrollViewer built in":  He means that the defaut ControlTemplate for ListBox includes a ScrollViewer.  This means it is not necessary to set ListBox.Template.  Also, note that if you are really set on using a Canvas (generally a bad idea), you could always set an explicit Height on the ListBox to force the ScrollViewer to appear.  Also check out the ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility attached property if you want scrollbars visible all the time.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed and changed my canvas to a grid and works well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try putting a ScrollViewer around your Grid inside the ItemsPanelTemplate?

```
    <ScrollViewer>
        <Grid ShowGridLines="True" IsItemsHost="True" Background="{DynamicResource LoadedImage}"  
                  Name="grdMain">
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: What for?  The problem is the Canvas, as Guy explains in his answer.